# Israelites/Jews descended from the Yadu?

Tags: mahabharata, rama, chandravansh, yadavas

A number of people have opined that the Israelite/Jewish nation descended from the Yadu clan (Yadavas), and that the Mahabharata 'proves' this (such as [here](http://viewzone2.com/nephilim.html), [here](http://ireport.cnn.com/docs/DOC-398075), [here](https://ramanan50.wordpress.com/tag/mahabharata-war/) and [here](https://books.google.com.au/books?id=WOQ5bucsDyAC&pg=PA23&lpg=PA23&dq=jews+mahabharata&source=bl&ots=oKm-XZWKzX&sig=n6DbucqDSvz7gesaQv_kE9OQFH8&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0CEkQ6AEwCWoVChMIoZHLkdutxwIVaHxyCh0whgwc#v=onepage&q=jews%20mahabharata&f=false)). E.g., some argue "Ram" is a variation of "Abraham", Jews' spiritual impact on the world is due to their connection with Sri Krishna, etc. It all sounds rather thinly-supported to me, but are there any authorities or texts that support this interpretation?

Comment: The Hebrews could have inherited a lot of memes & genes from the Zoroastrians(Iranians) who themselves were estranged cousins of the Vedic tribes. I doubt the Hebrews descended from 'Hindus' .

Comment: [This article](http://ancientvoice.wikidot.com/article:puru-lineage) might be useful...

Comment: Druids are descandants of druhyu.

Answer (score 2):

Yadavas [did fight among themselves](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/m16/m16003.htm) and perished, but did not perish in a war, with Krishna and Arjuna on side and the others, as mentioned in this [article](http://viewzone2.com/nephilimx.html).  Further, this incident occurred near sea coast, whereas Magadha was in a far off place.

So it is very difficult to link Jews with Yadavas, though the names are apparently indicting the same origin.

---

Some of the Yadavas might have migrated to Western lands from Dwaraka, which lies in the Western coast of India and carried their traditions with them.

However, the story of Adam and Eve from the Holy texts of Jews/Christians had origins in Rig Veda and Upanishad, where epithets was mentioned about deep spiritual concepts.

In [Rig Veda I.164.20](https://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv01164.htm) and in [3.1.1 of Mundaka Upanishad (page 51)](https://estudantedavedanta.net/Mundaka_and_Mandukya_Upanishads%20-%20Swami%20Sarvanand%20%5BSanskrit-English%5D.pdf), there was a mention about 2 birds perching on a branch of a tree.

> दवा सुपर्णा सयुजा सखाया समानं वर्क्षं परि षस्वजाते | तयोरन्यः पिप्पलं
> सवाद्वत्त्यनश्नन्नन्यो अभि चाकशीति ||
>
> Two Birds with fair wings, knit with bonds of friendship, in the
> same sheltering tree have found a refuge. One of the twain eats the
> sweet Fig-tree's fruitage; the other eating not regardeth only.

The first bird represents a ***Jiva, or individual self***, or soul. She has a female nature, being a shakti, an energy of God. When the jiva becomes distracted by the fruits (signifying sensual pleasure), she momentarily forgets her lord and lover and tries to enjoy the fruit independently of him. This separating forgetfulness is maha-maya, or enthrallment, spiritual death, and constitutes the fall of the jiva into the world of material birth, death, disease and old age.

The second bird is the **Atma**, an aspect of God who accompanies every living being in the heart while she remains in the material world. He is the support of all beings and is beyond sensual pleasure.

The epithets **Atma and Jiva** might have been converted into **Adam and Eve** and people of that area might have created a story of lost Paradise.

Answer (score 0):

to understand the above comment takes a lifetime of study, study what the people were doing 5000 years ago and study their similarities to the modern times. It says in the ancient times people were dependent on prayers to survive and if the prayers were not answered they would substitute to another god such as sun god. Making ref to Sungod, due to Egypt and the Jews were in Egypt. As Krishna had answered the prayers of the Pandavas, and the Yadavas then there would be no reason for them to leave India. However, karna's prayers were not answered, he was the son of sun god, he ruled Angraj in the Mahabharat times, and its possible, but no evidence, that its subject were similar to Indians today who live in different countries, very family orientated but have know interest in serving their own motherland, or in ancient time their own kingdom, which could be Angraj. So is the reason for Egypt to start as Sun God Dynasty and Jews as their workers or other. here they believe their prayers would be answered as they weren't answered in the Mahabharat times. You got to know the difficulties people were facing and similarities of today, if you do not understand they you need to study what was relevant, Egypt history is relevant whilst Jews were only the subjects. In the Mahabharat, people were gaining mantras to make appear weapons, if you were not competent to achieve these mantras then you would not succeed, this would create the haves and haves not, as it is today but an ancient version, to 'haves' was to have divine blessings, powers, mantras, prayers, destiny... So the Sungod's son named Karna and Jews were not competent, hence similar other subjects would come to the conclusion that they would have to leave India and start elsewhere. Only point is we cannot point which kingdom of India the Jews were related to, as no one has come up with evidence, unless someone knows, they can write the answer.

Comment: Hi, please split your answer into paragraphs and add references that supports your answer.

Comment: this is not an essay site, and there are no reference, all we know is many pages describe Arjuna as NAR as in the aspect of NARAYANA, and Karna is the western version but the west unknown at that time so cannot ref it. After the Mahabharat, the westerners were the Jews and the Egyptians. All this is difficult for some to understand because like we did not have a western path in ancient times, today we do not have an eastern or spiritual path, and each do not coincide with each other but exit in different times.

Comment: the above story, and then to leave India as you were not competent In ancient times with mantras etc...and caste system as a good person with punya got good birth and those with lower births could not compete i.e in the royal arena, there would be an argument of inequality, hence it formed the basis of the western civilisation, they changed the game today.

Comment: Basically, when discussing the Mahabharat, we have to rewrite it as, it is really a story that divided one race into East, Middle and West. so the Jews and Egyptian who are the beginning of the western civilisation really started in the Mahabharat story, but very small scale at that time, and for destiny reason people are not supposed to know where they origin from, but today you can know it as the Karma caused by the Mahabharat has been paid off now by the Indians. You can now spread this knowledge to all to unite back all the people

Comment: providing a reference is the rule here.  Check [Guidelines for new users answering questions](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/q/125/6981)

Answer (score -1):

We can draw parallels in mythologies...

Egyptians probably descended from the Aryans, who used similar design of chariots in war. In the the Mahabharata war, Karna the unlucky powerful son of the Sun-god lacked Brahma Gyan essential for a good life.

Arjuna surrendered to lord Krishna became competent to realize his potential and destiny.

But Karna even though being his elder brother was deprived of his kingdom, did not get a relationship with his own biological mother Kunti, and his prayers to Krishna did not work for him, hence he had no chance of success and was so luckless..

The Earth let his chariot sink into the ground... only material knowledge without divine guidance lead to his downfall, you needed Brahmagyan surrendering knowledge and the prayers to God in order to succeed in those days.

So also some 1000 years later when this similar problem fell to Tuthmosis the 2nd... he likewise did not get well with his mother, she continued to be an obstacle to his success in his life, so he carved out all details of his mother in an idol Hatsheput discovered in modern days.

This aspect can be compared to is the 2nd life of Karna, where he took royal support and protection from adopted parents.

so Egypt was the first western civilisation and the Mahabharat is really a story that divided us all into West, Middle, and East.

And so maybe the East started with Karna, the solar dynasty like Egypt and then many other solar worship places came up later such as Troy and Iran..

Jewish people may have been tribes in those days but don't know which indian dynasty to link it to, a guess could be Angraj which was given to Karna by Duryodhana, a lower kingdom it was described, pretty much like what the nri'S have got these days ( just a guesswork)

(Free edit mode Narasimham )

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! You answer looks bit difficult to read and understand. Make it clear. Visit [answer], take a look at [formatting help](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/editing-help). Use paragraph and lineebrakes. , For citing sources, use block-quotes.

Comment: I keep getting email from this site saying  'You answer looks bit difficult to read and understand'. this is not for an essay or English test, and to understand it, you need a lifetime of learning. please stop your emails, your emails does not have an option to unsubscribe

Comment: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/36001/hinduism-and-judaism-connection   Earlier posted on the topic