# Defending and saving the religion

Tags: dharma, culture

I have been wandering my mind over saving my religion. Sanatan religion is dying today facing extreme bashing,abuse, conversion etc.

1. Is there any scripture which say something about this and hindus?
2. What scriptures say for people like me in the situation like am in?

Comment: @NewUseroop Let's continue discussion in [Hinduism chatroom](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15189/hinduism)

Comment: Somewhat related: https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/how-can-one-save-sanatana-dharma @NewUseroop

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can one save Sanatana Dharma?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/questions/27566/how-can-one-save-sanatana-dharma)

Comment: @Rickross Since the question has been edited it is no longer what I have been asking. Its edited version resemble the question you gave link to in your latest coment. However,for the sake of purpose of this website I would make a request to revert the changes if it can be.

Comment: Ok , you are right .. but if the original version is retained even then your question might still be closed. And, the current version is clearly a duplicate. But I will retract my close vote @NewUseroop

Comment: @NewUseroop Welcome to Hinduism Stack Exchange! We should avoid name calling or blaming to any particular religion, politics, gender, caste etc becuse it can be rude/offensive speech towards them. Read the [Code of Conduct](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/conduct) for more information. I have edited your question body couple of time to fix it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/112115/discussion-on-question-by-new-user-oop-defending-and-saving-the-religion).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well you don't have to worry about all this, just do your duty without thinking about the outcomes of it. Following is the famous verse from the Bhagawad Geeta, which basically says:

**Shri Krishna says in [Bg. 4.7](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/7/):**

> यदा यदा हि धर्मस्य ग्लानिर्भवति भारत ।
> अभ्युत्थानमधर्मस्य तदात्मानं सृजाम्यहम् ॥ ७ ॥

> yadā yadā hi dharmasya
> glānir bhavati bhārata
> abhyutthānam adharmasya
> tadātmānaṁ sṛjāmy aham

**Translation**

> Whenever and wherever there is a decline in religious practice, O descendant of Bharata, and a predominant rise of irreligion – at that time I descend Myself.

Also in **[Bg. 4.8](https://vedabase.io/en/library/bg/4/8/)**

> परित्राणाय साधुनां विनाशाय च दुष्कृताम् ।
> धर्मसंस्थानार्थाय सम्भवामि युगे युगे ॥ ८ ॥

> paritrāṇāya sādhūnāṁ
> vināśāya ca duṣkṛtām
> dharma-saṁsthāpanārthāya
> sambhavāmi yuge yuge

**Translation**

> To deliver the pious and to annihilate the miscreants, as well as to reestablish the principles of religion, I Myself appear, millennium after millennium.

Comment: Does Vedas have something similar or identical to these Shlokas?

Comment: Well Gita is in a way abridged version of the Vedas.

Comment: I am not in position if agreeing or disagreeing because I do not know this. But if there is something in Vedas please cite that also if possibke

Comment: On a side note I would like to add that Indian sub-continent has been facing threats from the invaders be it arabs/mughals/britishers for more than 1400 years now, but we are here as we were before, so just carry on with your duties and responsibilities like our ancestors!

Comment: That is the biggest lie. We have already lost afghan pak and bangladesh.

Comment: Well nothing ever remains constant, it never will. One of the teachings of Vedas!

Comment: it is not answering the question.

Comment: I though you will get it. Once USSR was a big country, now all shattered. Once Alexander/Genghis Khan captured huge land now where is Greece/Mongolia? Once Ottoman empire was a huge one, now just Turkey. Once all continents were together, now we have 7. So why worry about pak/afg/bangladesh?

Comment: It is positive way of thinking. Other way round... It can also be interpreted to say Vedas says Vedas will cease to exist. That is why I am asking scriptural references.

Comment: Well Vedas are also known as Eternal Knowledge and what ever happens their wisdom will remain intact! Btw Bhagawad Gita is also a part of scriptures.

Comment: See I did not deny Bhagwat Geeta are not scriptures but I asked something from Vedas also. And if nothing is constant we hindus will cease to exist right?

Comment: No one is immortal, be it from any religion. But Hindus are not just confined to India, they are everywhere in the world, we just forget to count them and also we need to understand that sikhs/jains/buddhist etc are also Hindus coz Hinduism is part of Sanatam dharma and is basically way of living as has been described in the Vedas and other scriptures.

Comment: Question is not of mortality of humans but of survival of Dharma. Will Hinduism surivive this is the question. Now sikhs also claim themselves of abrahamic origin.

Comment: Hinduism is the oldest surviving religion, hope you are aware. As for sikhs, well Guru Granth Sahib the book they follow is just the essence of Vedas, Gita, Ramayam etc. do read/hear it someday, Guru Nanak was born to Hindu parents so let them claim whatever they want to.

Comment: Infact even Jesus and Mohammed was born to a Hindu parent for all Europe and Arab peninsula had Devi temples.

Comment: Read Rig Veda VII.18, wherein Sudas, attacked by 10 kings, saved by Indra.  Sudas was the follower of Vedic Dharma @NewUseroop

Comment: @SrimannarayanaKV can you write it as an answer in a little elaborative manner? It will be of much help

Comment: @New User oop - If this does not answer your question, why did you accept it?

Answer (score 2):

In Rig Veda, the poets are the sages, who heard the DIVINE knowledge, while they were in meditation, composed the mantras.

The epithets like AGNI, INDRA, VISHNU, etc, used in Rig Veda, all indicate the various aspects of the same Almighty God.

---

The Abrahamic religions were not in existence when the mantras of Rig Veda were composed.  If we deeply ponder over the roots of Abrahamic religions, we can find that [they emanated from Sanatana Dharma](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/a/36181/3869) only.

So the mention of Christianity or Islam or some other Abrahamic religion does not find place in Rig Veda.

The seers of Rig Veda did mention about praises of the Almighty, seeking protection from demons, ill-doers, etc, which can interpreted suiting to the present times, as the Almighty God will protect those, who  have **real faith in that POWER.**

---

The following are a few such mantras, which invoke the protection of the Almighty.

Rig Veda I.37.15

> Protect us from the demon, ***o Agni.*** Protect us from the malice of the
> enemy. Protect from the man who does harm or who seeks to smash us, o
> youngest one with lofty beams.

Rig Veda I.61.14, **praises Indra**

> Just this one—in fear of his birth both the ***firmly fixed mountains and
> heaven and earth thrust against each***. Constantly calling upon him
> [=**Indra**], who is a (**protective) arm for the seeker**, in an instant
> Nodhas [=the poet] will be (there) for his [=Indra’s] (next?) manly
> deed.

Rig Veda I.76.3

> Burn away all demonic beings, Agni. Become for the sacrifices the
> protector from curses. Then convey here the lord of soma with his two
> fallow bays. We have made a guest reception for him who gives well.

---

Some translators say the mantras in VII.18 refer to **Battle of the Ten Kings**, against Vedic follower Sudas.  Some other scholars say, those mantras are referring to SPIRITUAL aspects.

This confusion arose because the seer Vasistha composed those mantras in such a esoteric manner, they can be interpreted in any manner.

**So coming to Battle of the Ten Kings.**

This very famous hymn, the first in Vasiṣṭha’s Indra cycle, relates, if we can use so
positive a term, the so-called Battle of the Ten Kings, in which King Sudās and his
Bharata followers, with Indra on their side, defeat an alliance of ten kings, which includes their former allies, the Pūrus.

The following are a few mantras from VII.18, which indicate the battle.

> 5. Even the floods that had spread out—Indra made them into fords easy to cross for Sudās. Śimyu, who was vaunting himself above our newer
>    speech—he [=Indra] made him into the flotsam of the rivers and his
>    taunts (too).
> 6. Turvaśa Yakṣu (the “sacrificer”) was himself the offering cake—also the Matsyas [“fish”], whetted down (in their quest) for wealth, like
>    fish in water. The Bhr̥gus and the Druhyus (just) followed orders.
>    (Former) comrade crossed (former) comrade on the two opposing (sides).
> 7. The Pakthas [“cooked oblations”?] and the Bhalānases [“raiders”?] spoke out, and the Alinas, the Viṣānins, and the Śivas: “The feasting
>    companion of the Ārya [=Indra?], who led (us?) hither— with desire for
>    cattle for the Tr̥tsus he has gone with battle against superior men
>    [=us].”
> 8. The ill-intentioned ones without insight, causing Aditi to abort, diverted (the course of) the (river) Paruṣṇī. With his greatness he
>    [=Indra? Turvaśa?] enveloped the earth, being master (of it). The poet
>    lay there, being perceived as (just) a (sacrificial) animal.
> 9. They came to the Paruṣṇī, to a failed end as if to their (real) goal. Not even the swift one made it home for supper. Indra made those
>    without alliance (to us) subject to Sudās, those, easy to thrust away,
>    who, (though) in Manu’s (race), were of gelded speech.

---

Comment: Your last paragraph suggests that you might still need to conclude your answer. Kindly go for it.

Comment: You have a keen eye :-).  Your question requires that much answer only.  Shall I remove the last para? @NewUseroop

Comment: That I leave to your judgement for you must have gathered knowledge to write that. If writing more could lead to more perfect answer please write more. Else removal will be more good

Comment: @NewUseroop: I have deleted the last para. :-)